# How can I use my own snippets by using yasnippet in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I installed yasnippet and it works fine with default snippets.But I can't add my own snippets. To expand a string `php` to `<?php ?>`, I've done like this.

I wrote in my init file like this.

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(setq yas-snippet-dirs
      '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"
        "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/yasnippet/snippets"
        ))
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

I created `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/php.yasnippet` and wrote

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: php tag
# --
<?php $1 ?>
```

and call function `yas-reload-all`.

But I can't expand the string `php` in the web-mode.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do something else?